# mail website forum under one database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've tried to find answer to my question but i couldn't find the right answer yet (would be glad if you point me to one). I'm a newbie when it comes to running services (websites, forum, wikis, emails). I'm rather experimenting.

I have couple of websites (mainly wordpress), mail server, forum, wikis, and file sharing (owncloud) hosted on one server.

Until now every time I would install new service I would create new database (mysql), just like the install readme's would advice. I would like to connect some of the services together. Mainly unified user database. 
What is the best way to do it. Is having multiple databases versus one db heavier for my servers cpu load? Is it secure? Is it easy to administrate it?
If cpu load isn't issue while having multiple db's is it possible to create user database and link it to the services databases i would like to link it to?

Comment: MySQL "databases" are actually "schemas". There is only a single database on a mysql server. The schemas can talk to each other and you can have foreign keys across schemas. Or you can set security on the schemas. Pretty lightweight too. Secure. Easy to admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple applications (forum, wiki, ...) access the same database is not likely to have any effect on CPU usage, but there are other drawbacks:

- Table names used by applications might have conflicts (many of them might have a "session" or "posts" table). Some web apps have a feature to prefix table names with a string, like "wp_session" and "wp_posts" for example to get around conflicts.
- Yes, it's less secure. When one of the applications has a security hole and someone manages to access its database, data of all applications is compromised.
- Multiple databases is likely to be easier to manage when doing application upgrades, backups, removing or adding applications to the mix.
- Accidentally break one database, and you'll break all apps.

To get the applications use the same authentication database it's usually not enough to point them at the same database, as they're likely to use a different database schema for storing user information (different columns in the auth database), different hashing for password storage, and so on.

The question is quite broad, and the specific answer depends a lot on the actual applications you're using. The best approach in general is probably to pick applications which support a protocol such as OpenID or OAuth, or an authentication backend such as an LDAP database or PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module). These methods allow you to use a single user database managed by a single method. The apps all need to work with the same backend. In any case, it's likely to be quite a learning experience to get it running smoothly.